# Is there a way to set a queue name in rabbitTemplate with spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to set a queue name with rabbitTemplate. Is there a way to do that?

Trying to set a queue name with rabbitTemplate.

Try the rabbitTemplate.convernAndSend method but u cant set the queueName.

Am i need other methods to doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant find any solution with rabbitTemplate. rabbitAdmin solve my problem.

```
RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
```